# experience system for a game

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pygame

I have a question for anyone that has made a game text base or anything about the system for calculating exp for a character. Does an exp system require a massive amount of code?

I did a little trial on it ill post the code, and after the little bit I did do (not much by the way) it seems like to program a leveling system would require a lot of code.

Can anyone, please, explain (not step by step) but give me an idea of what it would take, or give an example of code for a leveling system. since im still new to programming my code is still written pretty long.

```
import random

exp=0

a=1
while a==1:
    print" you are fighting you kill you get xp"
    xp=random.randint(20, 30)
    exp+=xp
    print"you got, "+str(exp)+" xp"
    if exp>=300:
        print"congradulations you are level 2"
        break
```

Comment: It depends on what kind of leveling system you want. A complex leveling system is likely to require more code than a very simple one. It all depends on what you mean by "a lot of code" as well. Your approach above could be generalized to n levels in probably 15 or 20 lines.

Comment: You might like to ask your question at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ after formulating a more concrete question.

Comment: @rogaos-Im still fairly new to python, just started up again a couple days ago. after taking a long break. I dont want a complex exp system but for example. If I had 3 different skill (mining, att, summon) and if level cap was at 60. would i need to write out code for each level. for example if level==2: random.randint(30, 60) then again for 3 and so on for each level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how Python works exactly but I'm sure you can give an XP attribute per "monster" to denote the XP gain. [MONSTER CLASS :O](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) (Perhaps you can randomize it between values to add a little bit of more depth.)
`xp=random.randint(20, 30)` <--- exactly what I'm talking about.

As far as Level gaining you don't need some long if statement you can probably create an algorithm to get to the next level.

```
if(currentXP*currentlevel*.65 > currentXP) level up();
```

Keep track of `currentXP` and your `currentLevel` and play with this accordingly.

`.65` is a pretty arbitrary scale, however, that's that part that needs to be tested. Are people leveling up too fast? Do we need to make it harder to get to the next level? and so forth. Keep toying with it until you are pleased. This is very basic, you can probably make something less linear.

Comment: @progenhard-im still new to programming that txt based game that i posted on here is my first actual game I made. so bear with me please lol. the speed of leveling of course will be tested but for right now im just trying to figure out exactly how much code..or amount of time (ball park average) it would take to code an exp system for one skill. If you have ever played like runescape or a game like that how they calculate xp per level and xp per item.

Comment: @user2423223 I don't think the "leveling" system itself will take that much code to be honest You probably could condense it to 3 lines of code if you want it simple. The expensive part is how you want to define your monsters, items, spells, ect. These are all objects and need attributes that you need to assign. For instance, a monster `troll[health = 10, attack = 2-3, xp = 30-40]` Then you need to define a different one for each monster you create.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something exceptional... The given formula for levelling up could be reduced to `currentlevel*.65 > 1`, which will make you level up every time xp is gained, if the level is above `1` :)